# Why doesn't VPython in trinket let me rotate objects with my mouse? It runs the code just fine but I cant drag around anything

Tags: jupyter-lab, vpython

Pretty much the title. Tried creating a sphere and a box which worked, but can't rotate it around at all. I can zoom in and out though.

Couldn't find anything online, tried using jupyterlab and had the same problem. Can zoom in and out but nothing else

Answer (score 0):

There is a strange bug with the VPython trinket, where it focuses the code and not the VPython window; so, you have to re-run it and make sure to not click the code window, then it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was having a problem with right-clicking as well but it seems fixed now.